# What should we plan to see on a weekend in Belfast?

Tags: planning, northern-ireland

I'm planning a weekend in Belfast with 3 friends around mid-October.
The only things we planned for now are the Crusaders-Ballymena footall game on the saturady afternoon (yeah, we're kinda soccer freaks), and of course the murals.

We are interested in museums, historic places, good pubs, good live music places. We are not much into churches and religious places.

What else would be a "must-see" in Belfast during that short trip?

Comment: Please try to make your question a little more specific. What sort of things are you interested in?

Comment: Yeah, murals! They can actually take a whole day, as they are spread out and you should really see both republican and protestant ones to have a better perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Belfast is awesome place. There are many attractions in Belfast. I recommend you visit Grand Opera House  , Royal Ulster Rifles Museum  , Belvoir Park Golf Club , The Odyssey  , Queens Film Theatre  , Ulster Museum,  Titanic Dock and Pump House , City Hall  etc.Last time  during my Europe travel I visited Belfast it is really beautiful place.